# Matching sequence of numbers in URL after specific text

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to match a sequence of numbers that comes after "job=" while ignoring what comes before it and after it like "list.php?job=11534&name"

Below I've posted what I have so far, which seems to have no affect on the URL.
Also, will [L] only stop the rewrite engine if the rule matches or no matter what?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Current Rule:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)job=([^&]+)
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /positions/job/$1 [L]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Don't you have to add the `?` char in `^|&|\?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$`  will match requests that contain only numbers (`/4666`), this regular expression should be placed in the RewriteCond instead, `%1` will refer to it, and  the trailing ? in the rewriterule exclude the query string from the new url (is that what you want?).

`L` will stop the rewrite engine for the current url only if the rule matches.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)job=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^.+$ /positions/job/%1? [L]
```

if you want to redirect the user to the new URL, add R to the rewriterule options (`[L,R=301]`),

be careful that these directives will redirect any url where the query string matches `job=([0-9]+)` to the new url, if you wanna to restrict the redirection to certain requests(like `/folder/list.php?job=qsd&name=qsd`), be sure to include them in the rewrite rule, so the directives would be :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)job=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^folder/list\.php$ /positions/job/%1? [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I see why you made the change, but when I try this I get taken to the homepage URL?

Comment: this is exactly what these directives do, if you want the new url to be displayed in the user browser, add R to RewriteRule  options [L,R=301]